# Hiring someone for my Thesis

Tags: thesis

I want to set up my PhD thesis, given a template. The problem is that I have to put inside my papers, which are all from different authors and with different packages. I am willing to pay for that. Is there anyone willing to help?

Comment: Welcome. There are services, but it is off-topic here.

Comment: Try to update your profile so that people can reach out to you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273755/318909

Comment: Updating your profile is worth trying since you do not have enough reputation to participate in a chat: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3673/177

Comment: @geremia Since this has been closed, I can be more frank: I'm willing to help. I've done the same for my thesis and can understand your needs.